# create a data set with only the NA rows in R

Tags: r, dataset, na

How can I create a new data set based on NA value.

```
                      Date Symbol     Close
1      2005-01-03 01:20:00      A 115.87094
2      2005-01-03 01:25:00      A 115.88168
3      2005-01-03 01:30:00      A 115.88168
4      2005-01-03 01:35:00      A        NA
5      2005-01-03 01:40:00     NA 115.87094
6      2005-01-03 01:45:00     NA 115.87094
7      2005-01-03 01:50:00      A 115.86020
```

i just want to keep the rows with NA in the row

```
                    Date   Symbol     Close
4      2005-01-03 01:35:00      A        NA
5      2005-01-03 01:40:00     NA 115.87094
6      2005-01-03 01:45:00     NA 115.87094
```

Comment: `subset(df, is.na(Symbol) | is.na(Close))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `complete.cases`

```
df1[!complete.cases(df1),]
#                 Date Symbol    Close
#4 2005-01-03 01:35:00      A       NA
#5 2005-01-03 01:40:00   <NA> 115.8709
#6 2005-01-03 01:45:00   <NA> 115.8709
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm relatively a beginner but you could iterate through the rows (not sure about how you might do it with apply or other vectorized functions) using anyNA() on the row and then if it is true keep the row.

EDIT:
e.g.

```
a <- rep(NA, nrow(df))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  a[i] <- anyNA(df[i, ])
}

newdf <- df[a, ]
```

Generally style guides recommend against over using loops, but the anyNA() and is.na() functions are super useful so worth knowing anyways.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: `df[apply(df, 1, anyNA),]`